# Convert List<string> to Model class

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-core, type-conversion

Having issue with converting List to Student object in c#.

I have a C# model class as below:

```
public class Student{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string StudentName{get; set;}
   public string StudentAddress{get; set;}
   public string StudentRemarks{get; set;}
   public string AdditionalInfo{get;set;}
}
```

I have another class where I have a List which holds data as below (Since this is just a list of string, it won't have any property names in front of it such as 'ID: 001') Note: This string will not have any data for 'AdditionalInfo'.

```
001
John, Snow
NewYork
Sample test info
```

Now I have another class where I wanted to convert this List to my 'Student' class where 001 has to be assigned to ID, John Snow has to be assigned to 'StudentName', NewYork has to be assigned to 'StudentAddress', Sample test info has to be assigned to 'StudentRemarks'. Since this doesn't have any data provided for 'AdditionalInfo' property, this should be assigned with empty or null value in it. Here is the class

```
public class StudentInfoService
{
    public List<string> GetStudentInfo(string data)
    {
        var studentData = new List<string>();

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(data))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                var data = line.Split('|');
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    studentData.Add(item);
                }
                studentData.ConvertAll(c => (Student)c); //Here is where I am struggling to convert the list string to model class
            }
        }
        return studentData ;
    }
}
```

The issue is, I want to convert the list to 'Student' object and automatically assign all the data to the respective properties by order(there won't be any null or empty data in between other than the 'AdditionalInfo'). Student object will have only one student record. It won't have a list of records. So I need to convert the List to Student object. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and clarify the question. In particular it is quite unclear what data format is - sample text shown in the post has no pipes as separators, but code split on '|'. Also there is way too much code that is not related to what question is potentially asking - which I believe is "having `strnig[4]` how to set individual properties of `new Student()` to 0-3 items in the string array". Ideally you should [edit] the question to have just enough code and all necessary data inline in the code like `string d[] = new[]{"001", "Jon", "NY", "Sample"};`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write code to map lines of text to a model instance, e.g.

```
public Student GetStudent(List<string> list)
{
    return new Student
    {
        ID = int.Parse(list[0]),
        StudentName = list[1],
        StudentAddress = list[2],
        StudentRemarks = list[3],
        AdditionalInfo = (list.Count > 4) ? list[4] : null
    };
}
```